# HttpException: 500 when running a SPARQL query on remote endpoint

Tags: java, sparql, jena, endpoint

I'm very new to Semantic Web programming. I'm learning about how to write Java code to query a SPARQL endpoint using the Jena API.

Here's my Java code:

```
public class TestJena 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String queryString = "prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>" +
                        "select ?class where { " + 
                        " ?class a owl:Class } ";
    String endpoint = "http://localhost:8890/sparql";

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);

    query.setOffset(1);

    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(endpoint, query);

    try
    {
        ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();
        StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
        List<String> columnNames = resultSet.getResultVars();

        while(resultSet.hasNext())
        {
            QuerySolution solution = resultSet.next();

            for(String var : columnNames)
            {
                results.append(var + ":");

                if (solution.get(var) == null)
                    results.append("{null}");
                else if (solution.get(var).isLiteral())
                    results.append(solution.getLiteral(var).toString());
                else
                    results.append(solution.getResource(var).getURI());
                results.append('\n');
            }
            results.append("----------\n");
        }
        System.out.print("Results are : "+results.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
        qe.close();
    }
}
}
```

When I run the query, I get the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" HttpException: 500
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.rewrap(HttpQuery.java:414)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:358)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:295)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:346)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:338)
at com.TestJena.example.TestJena.main(TestJena.java:31)
```

When I run the above query at the endpoint `http://localhost:8890/sparql`, it runs fine.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is? Why is it throwing a **HttpException: 500** ?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is returning HTTP error code 500 (internal server failure). The client code looks just fine, maybe running an old version of Jena because it usually prints more details (if the remote end provides any).

When you use http://localhost:8890/sparql that is presumably an HTML form, not the SPARQL endpoint.  It may need additional parameters - see documentation of for that server.

Comment: I'm very new to Semantic Web. I do not understand what you've said. Why is it giving a HttpException?

Comment: Because the system you are querying is returning an HTTP 500 error. The code you show is simply reporting that.